# python3.4 on raspberry pi 3 cant find cv2 module

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, opencv3.0

I tried to install opencv2 to my raspberry pi 3 following this tutorial 
[pyimagesearch.com](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/26/how-to-install-opencv-3-on-raspbian-jessie/)
,I made it to the end. But when I tried to run a program, it shows ImportError : no module named 'cv2' as in this picture [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP3vn.png).
The program is running well on python2.7.9, but why it pop that error in python 3.4? How can I fix this error? If anyone can help me it would be much appreciated, because I need that program to run in python3.4. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my own problem haha.. All I need is to copy cv2.so from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cv2.so to /usr/lib/python3.4/cv2.so .... Tried my program after that, then it worked as good as in python2.7